# Registering created object in outer @autoreleasepool block and strange __weak pointer behavior

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

Code:

```
@autoreleasepool {

        id __autoreleasing obj = nil;

        @autoreleasepool {
            obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];

            _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
        }

        NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj); // Error
        _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
    }
```

From Clang documentation:

```
For __autoreleasing objects, the new pointee is retained, autoreleased, and stored into the lvalue using primitive semantics.
```

Why obj is autoreleased in inner @autoreleasepool block not in outer?

**Second example:**

```
@autoreleasepool {

        id __weak obj = nil;

        @autoreleasepool {
            id __strong obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
            obj = obj1;

            NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj); // <NSObject: 0x7857657>
            NSLog(@"obj retain count: %d", (int) _objc_rootRetainCount(obj1)); // 2

            _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
        }

        NSLog(@"obj retain count: %d", (int) _objc_rootRetainCount(obj)); // 1
        NSLog(@"obj: %@", obj); // (null)

        _objc_autoreleasePoolPrint();
    }
```

Why NSLog outputs "(null)" if retain count is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why obj is autoreleased in inner @autoreleasepool block not in outer?

The object is autoreleased in the assignment to `obj` (`obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];`), so it is put into the topmost (innermost) autorelease pool, and is released when that pool is drained (at the end of the `@autoreleasepool` block).

> Why NSLog outputs "(null)" if retain count is 1?

`_objc_rootRetainCount()` is not a documented function. Apparently `_objc_rootRetainCount(nil)` evaluates to 1.

Comment: ok. thanks. but I did not get answer why (null) is being printed.

Comment: @AndrewShmig: because `obj` is null (`nil`)